# How to reset package actions queue in Aptitude with its modern "Cancel pending actions" behavior?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, package-management, 20.10, aptitude

In previous Ubuntu 16.04 LTS version I used the following procedure in Aptitude to undo package installation or removal:

1. Start Aptitude curses by `sudo aptitude`
2. Select some package(s) to install or remove
3. Review the changes list
4. Hit <kbd>F10</kbd>, then from *Actions* choose *Cancel pending actions* to undo the selections made.

The above method fails with modern versions of Ubuntu like 18.04 LTS, 20.04 LTS and 20.10. This change is documented [in changelog](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/aptitude/-/blob/debian-sid/NEWS#L1524) from 2016-02-21 for Version 0.7.6.

How can get "Cancel pending actions" functionality in modern Ubuntu versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this conversation, this is not possible anymore.
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=816781#10

You have to revert your actions and mark the packages as `keep` instead of `install`.

To do it globally, you can use `sudo aptitude keep-all` which is useful because sometimes aptitude can take a lot of time trying to fix dependencies and you are stuck until it gives up.